# glDrawElements does not show anything when I move it to another method

Tags: c++, opengl

When I draw terrain like this - it works normal

```
void Terrain::RenderLandscape()
{
int x, y;
int Index = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < MapSize-1; i++)
{
    Index = 0;
    for (int j = 0;j < MapSize-1; j++)
    {   
        x = j * Zoom;
        y = i * Zoom;

        TextureMap[Index+0][0]= j * TextureBit;     
        TextureMap[Index+0][1]= i * TextureBit;
        TextureMap[Index+1][0]= j * TextureBit;
        TextureMap[Index+1][1]= (i+1) * TextureBit;

        VertexMap[Index+0][2] = HeightMap[j][i];            
        VertexMap[Index+1][2] = HeightMap[j][i+1];

        VertexMap[Index+0][0] = x;              
        VertexMap[Index+0][1] = y;
        VertexMap[Index+1][0] = x;
        VertexMap[Index+1][1] = y+Zoom;

        Index += 2;             
    }

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, Index, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, Indices);
}
}
```

But when I move loops to another method and leave in `RenderLandscape`

```
void Terrain::RenderLandscape()
{
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 512, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, Indices);
}
```

Where 512 - size of Indices array - It shows only black screen without terrain.

What is the problem?

I move loops to method which is called before `renderLandscape`. There I initialize `vertex`, `normals`, `texture` arrays. Method `init`.

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);           
glVertexPointer (3, GL_FLOAT, 0, VertexMap);

glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);    
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, TextureMap);

glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,0, NormalMap);

for (int Row = 0; Row < MapSize*2; Row++)   
{
    Indices[Row] = Row;
}

int x, y;
int Index = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < MapSize-1; i++)
{
    Index = 0;
    for (int j = 0;j < MapSize-1; j++)
    {   
        x = j * Zoom;
        y = i * Zoom;

        TextureMap[Index+0][0]= j * TextureBit;     
        TextureMap[Index+0][1]= i * TextureBit;
        TextureMap[Index+1][0]= j * TextureBit;
        TextureMap[Index+1][1]= (i+1) * TextureBit;

        VertexMap[Index+0][2] = HeightMap[j][i];            
        VertexMap[Index+1][2] = HeightMap[j][i+1];

        VertexMap[Index+0][0] = x;              
        VertexMap[Index+0][1] = y;
        VertexMap[Index+1][0] = x;
        VertexMap[Index+1][1] = y+Zoom;

        Index += 2;             
    }
}

Index = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < MapSize - 1; i++) 
{
    Index = 0;
    for (int j = 0;j < MapSize-1; j++)
    {
        CVector3 vTriangle[] = { CVector3(VertexMap[Index + 0]), 
                            CVector3(VertexMap[Index + 1]), 
                            CVector3(VertexMap[Index + 2]) };

        CVector3 normal = Normal(vTriangle);
        NormalMap[Index + 0][0] = normal.x;
        NormalMap[Index + 0][1] = normal.y;
        NormalMap[Index + 0][2] = normal.z;

        NormalMap[Index + 1][0] = normal.x;
        NormalMap[Index + 1][1] = normal.y;
        NormalMap[Index + 1][2] = normal.z;

        NormalMap[Index + 2][0] = normal.x;
        NormalMap[Index + 2][1] = normal.y;
        NormalMap[Index + 2][2] = normal.z;

        Index += 3;
    }
}
```

So it works like this
1) I initialize `opengl` and create `terrain` object.

```
........
landscape.Init();

glutPassiveMotionFunc(MousePassive);
glutIdleFunc(draw)
........
```

2) in method draw I call `renderLandscape` method

```
glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-20, 0, 0);
    glScalef(0.01, 0.01, 0.01);
    glRotatef(90, 1, 0, 0);
    landscape.RenderLandscape();
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Where are you setting the pointer that actually points to your vertices? The `glVertexPointer` call...

Comment: @aardvarkk, I've updated details.

Comment: This looks like it would be hard to debug without a fair bit more information. Check your arrays to make sure the data makes sense at each index. Check that the winding order is correct. Check that your translate, scale, and rotate aren't pushing your landscape behind the camera or something. Simplify as much as possible until you get something displayed on screen (say, just draw one triangle) and then slowly turn it back into the "complex version" checking along the way whether anything shows on screen.

Comment: @aardvarkk,The problem is that when I move it - I don't change anything else. How can actions in draw method affect on arrays at all. In debugger all arrays contains data in `renderlandscape` method. The more interesting thing that if I left loops and delete all lines except `index += 2` and j loop - it doesn't show anything too.

Comment: You are using client memory (e.g. CPU memory) instead of server memory (e.g. VRAM using VBOs) which, first of all is unsupported in modern OpenGL, and second has me wondering what the scopes of your arrays such as `VertexMap` are. You can easily be using dangling pointers in this sort of situation.

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman, my arrays - `protected : GLfloat VertexMap[MapSize * 2][3]; ` for example inside `terrain` object. Also about VRAM - what do you mean?

Comment: Well, you are storing your vertex data in system memory. Modern OpenGL (GL3) requires you to use Vertex Buffer Objects (VBOs), which are by all accounts stored in VRAM (GPU memory). In any case, your problem is actually related to setting up the vertex array pointers only once when you initialize your object; you need to do this every time you draw unless you use Vertex Array Objects (GL3 feature). You can compute the vertex arrays themselves only one time if that is all your application requires, but you (generally) have to setup the pointers every time you draw.

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman, so I need to recalculate normales and vertexes in `renderlandscape` every time? add all loops to `renderlandscape` method?

Comment: You do not need to re-calculate them, just make sure you set the pointers and enable the appropriate vertex arrays before you call `glDrawElements (...)`. This is especially important if you ever draw more than one instance of this class, because GL will keep track of the pointers for whatever object last called `init (...)` the way you have this implemented currently.

Comment: How? I mean how to check that pointers are set? Enable? You mean add `glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); glVertexPointer (3, GL_FLOAT, 0, VertexMap);` lines in `renderLandscape` method?

Comment: Don't check them, just make sure that the first few lines of `init (...)` that look like this: `glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);           
glVertexPointer (3, GL_FLOAT, 0, VertexMap);

glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);    
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, TextureMap);

glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,0, NormalMap);` are called every time before you draw. This way they will be setup appropriately, in case anything else that used Vertex Arrays changed the pointers since the last time you called this function.

Comment: @ Andon M. Coleman. So I need to add those lines in `renderLandscape`?